# regex to not allow continuous characters without space

Tags: regex, kotlin

Hi i am trying to not allow continuous characters without space assuming max length of word can be 25 chars.

Allowed -> hi there how are you i'm fine over here "dfsdfsd'"()sdfnjsd. fhhdfbsdfbdhhbdhfb.

Not Allowed-> hi there howareyou, **"()#jsdfhsdjfhjshdasdjasjdd34!fsdfsdfsddfsdfsdff*&**

What i have tried

This will allow only alphanumeric and certain special characters

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 ,()!'".\-_:/\\-]*$
```

but not sure how to find continuous Words length greater than 25 chars without space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a negative look ahead for 26 non whitespace chars that is anchored to start:

```
^(?!.*\S{26})[a-zA-Z0-9 ,()!'"._:/\\-]*$
```

The hyphen char `-` was in your character class twice; this regex has one of them removed.

Comment: Why use double hyphen inside the same character class? One is redundant and I'd remove the escaped one.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew good point. I just copy pasted OP’s character class. I will mention that

Answer (score 1):

You may check if a string contains 26 consecutive non-whitespace chars (with the `\S{26}` regex) and if it does, return false, else, return true.

```
val s = """hi there how are you i'm fine over here "dfsdfsd'"()sdfnjsd. fhhdfbsdfbdhhbdhfb."""
println(!"""\S{26}""".toRegex().containsMatchIn(s)) // => true

val s2 = """hi there howareyou, "()#jsdfhsdjfhjshdasdjasjdd34!fsdfsdfsddfsdfsdff*&"""
println(!"""\S{26}""".toRegex().containsMatchIn(s2)) // => false
```

The `.containsMatchIn` method searches for the pattern match anywhere in the whole input string.

You may further precise the pattern.